# Fill DataFrame column value with value from parent row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have DataFrame like this:

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| Key   | Parent   | Value   |
|-------+----------+---------|
| Key1  | Key10    | 246     |
| Key2  | Key1     | None    |
| Key3  | Key14    | 434     |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

Now I need to replace data in `Value` column (if it is None) with data from the `Parent` column (if parent exists - if not value should stay None). So expected results for above table should look like this:

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| Key   | Parent   | Value   |
|-------+----------+---------|
| Key1  | Key10    | 246     |
| Key2  | Key1     | 246     |
| Key3  | Key14    | 434     |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

DataFrame preparation code:

```py
data = [['Key1', "Key10", 246], ['Key2', "Key1", None], ['Key3', 'Key14', "434"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Key', 'Parent', 'Value'])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

use `map` and `fillna`

```
m = dict(df[['Key', 'Value']].values)
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(df['Parent'].map(m))
```

df

```
    Key     Parent  Value
0   Key1    Key10   246
1   Key2    Key1    246
2   Key3    Key14   434
```

Comment: To avoid the conversion to a dictionary, you can also just use a Series here for `m`. `m = df.set_index('Key')['Value']`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['Key1', "Key10", 246], ['Key2', "Key1", None], ['Key3', 'Key14', "434"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Key', 'Parent', 'Value'])

df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'].isnull(), 
                       df['Value'][df['Key'].isin(df['Parent'])], 
                       df['Value']
                       )

print(df)
```

```
    Key Parent Value
0  Key1  Key10   246
1  Key2   Key1   246
2  Key3  Key14   434
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
data = {
    'Key': ['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'],
    'Parent': ['Key10', 'Key1', 'Key14'],
    'Value': [246, None, 434]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Iterate over rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isna(row['Value']):  # Check if Value is None
        parent = row['Parent']
        if parent in df['Key'].values:  # Check if Parent exists in the Key column
            parent_value = df.loc[df['Key'] == parent, 'Value'].values[0]
            df.at[index, 'Value'] = parent_value
```